# hostname could not be parsed error when hitting custom MapHttpRoute

Tags: jss, docker, nextjs, custom-route

I am running Sitecore (10.2)/SXA backend in Docker. I am running NextJS directly on my host machine via `npm run start:connected`.

On upstream environments, when I hit `/export/doc?id=xxxxxxx`, a file is automatically downloaded. However, on my local I see this error:

[image: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed]

The Sitecore CM logs show this:

```
ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.UriFormatException
Message: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
Source: System
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.UriBuilder.get_Uri()
at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetRequestUri(HttpContextBase context)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.OverrideDialogs.Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnBeginRequest(HttpContextBase context)
at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.HttpApplication_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I'm not seeing any messages in my NextJS logs.

The route is mapped via this custom processor:

```
public class CustomRouterProcessor
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        Configure(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected void Configure(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapHttpRoute("exportDoc", "api/ExportAPI/ExportDoc", new
        {
            controller = "ExportAPI",
            action = "ExportDoc"
        });
    }
}
```

The same issue happens when I hit the same route on `cd.mysite.localhost` or `cm.mysite.localhost`, and the same error message always appears no matter what I set my host name configurations to. How can I go about locating which hostname it's referring to?